# How to focus next edit text in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have 2 EditText for each row in Listview. The rows maybe n numbers. I want to enter the value in 1st EditText in first row and then press next in soft keyboard. The focus should be go to 2nd EditText in 1st row. After than I will enter the value in 2nd EditText and press next in soft keyboard the focus should go to 2nd row 1st EditText. Herewith I attached my xml and adapter code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <com.vijay.textview.AutofitTextView
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/txt_component"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="@string/empty_string"
            android:textColor="@color/planned_schedule_list_item_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/bol_listview_font_size"/>

        <com.vijay.edittext.AutoFitEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_ready_to_go"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
            style="@style/scan_text_fields_white_bg"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="@color/planned_schedule_list_item_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/bol_listview_header_font_size"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:maxLength="5"
            android:nextFocusRight="@id/edt_damaged"/>

        <com.vijay.edittext.AutoFitEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_damaged"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
            style="@style/scan_text_fields_white_bg"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="@color/planned_schedule_list_item_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/bol_listview_header_font_size"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:maxLength="5"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My adapter code is:

```
holder.edtReadyToGo.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                if (position + 1 != mData.size()) {
                mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(position+1);
                mListView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        AutoFitEditText nextField = (AutoFitEditText) holder.edtDamaged.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                        if (nextField != null) {
                            nextField.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }
                }, 200);
                return true;
               }

            }else if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                holder.edtReadyToGo.setCursorVisible(false);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    holder.edtDamaged.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                if (position + 1 != mData.size()) {
                    mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(position+1);
                    mListView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            AutoFitEditText nextField = (AutoFitEditText) holder.edtReadyToGo.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                            if (nextField != null) {
                                nextField.requestFocus();
                            }
                        }
                    }, 200);
                    return true;
                }

            } else if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                holder.edtDamaged.setCursorVisible(false);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here my 2nd EditText(edt_damaged) working fine. When I click next it automatically focus to next field. But 1st EditText(edt_ready_to_go) not working. Please help me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by setting

- listview to android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
- listview to setItemsCanFocus(true);
- set your activity to
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: I will try and let you know..!!

Comment: It's working fine. But when It comes to last row it showing done in 1st edit text. So that we can not move to 2nd edit text in last row. Any idea.??

Comment: change android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to "adjustPan"

Comment: have you removed other code for listview that you have tried before.I have implemented one example code and it is working fine for me

Comment: Yes.. I removed all.. Can you post that sample if you don't mind.. Please..