# How to focus next listview Multiline edittext item on imeOption click

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I  have listview with **multiline** edittext. Now i want  to focus next item edittext when user click ImeOption.

I was tried this solution but not working. [Focus next item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404149/how-to-focus-next-edit-text-in-listview)

I have view like below:

[image: task list view]

User can add new item on click of add sign.

Now suppose user now write anything in first item edittext then when user click imeOption next then next item edittext should be focused.

My adapter Code is here:[My adapter code](https://hastebin.com/ruwavodihu.java)

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: @SagarNayak i was already  post link below

Answer (score 0):

You can try by below setting into your view and manifest file:

listview to android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"

listview to setItemsCanFocus(true);

your single view  android:maxLines="1"

your single view  android:singleLine="true"

and as usually imeoption is same

set your activity to

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" into manifest file.

Hope it helps you

Comment: please paste it above don't give me link because i cannot access it

Comment: please check my updated ans i solved it and test it also and it's working 100%

Comment: ohh let me try on multiline

Comment: i want something like this http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/iOS-7-Reminders-Creating-Reminders.gif

Comment: brother this is single line not multiline i seen gif file

Comment: i know but i dont have that gif its downloaded if you want to check than check reminder app of iphone]